# Draw HTML content to existing PDDocument with openhtmltopdf

Tags: spring-boot, pdfbox, openhtmltopdf

I am having an already existing implementation of drawing PDF-s in SpringBoot with Apache PdfBox library.

However, now there is a requirement to add text with HTML tags to an existing document.

From what I have researched, PDFBox does not recognize HTML tags, so I reached for [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) library. But, I am having issues doing so, don't know how to pass the current location of the document I want the text to be appended to. Also, I need to extract the location to where the next text should be appended to.

Is it possible to do it with this library, or you suggest some other option?

```
PdfBoxRenderer renderer = new PdfRendererBuilder()
            .withProducer(htmlText)
            .usePDDocument(document)
            .buildPdfRenderer();
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDFWithoutClosing();
    renderer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static void htmlToPdf(String inputHTML, String outputPdf) throws IOException {

       
       // ByteArrayOutputStream actual = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File Outputfile = new File(outputPdf);
        try {
            PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
            builder.defaultTextDirection(BaseRendererBuilder.TextDirection.LTR);
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(Outputfile);
             float POINTS_PER_INCH = 72;
            float POINTS_PER_MM = 1 / (10 * 2.54f) * POINTS_PER_INCH;
            PDPage page1 = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
            page1.setMediaBox(new PDRectangle(297 * POINTS_PER_MM, 210 * POINTS_PER_MM));
            
            //document.addPage(page1);
            builder.usePDDocument(document);
            builder.withHtmlContent(inputHTML, "")
                .usePageSupplier((doc, pageWidth, pageHeight, pageNumber, shadowPageNumber) -> {
                PDPage page;
                if (pageNumber == 0) {
                    //First appending page is last original page.
                    page = doc.getPage(doc.getNumberOfPages() -1);
                    System.out.println(0);
                } else {
                    doc.addPage(page = page1);
                    System.out.println(1);
                }
                return page;
            });

            //builder.toStream(actual);
            builder.addDOMMutator(doc -> {
                Element style = doc.createElement("style");
                Node node = doc.createTextNode(
                        "@page:first { margin-top: 400px; size: landscape; } " 
                            + "@page { margin-: 0mm; size: landscape; }" + ".MainTable > *{ margin-left: 150px; }"+" .MainTable {page-break-inside: avoid;}");
                style.appendChild(node);
                doc.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(style);
            });
            builder.useFastMode();
            builder.testMode(true);
            //builder.run();
            PdfBoxRenderer renderer = builder.buildPdfRenderer();
            renderer.createPDFWithoutClosing();
           
            document.save(outputPdf);
           // actual.close();
            System.out.println("Finished");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I also very tried , But Yesterday I found the solution create html content to existing  pdDocument. This Might be very useful . Thanks